# Running multiplay test with junit and TAURUS

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jmeter, performance-testing

I hope that someone can help me and this post can be a help for others. I have a project where I need to test page load. The performance tool is `TAURUS`. The project is with a login page(token).

**The question is:**

How can I perform page load test for a specific page when I have the login form. Below is the example of my code.

Or when I have a big dependent test and in the test I have 10 different pages and some pages contain attachment files, how is possible to tell the test that I want to measure page load time of different pages?

```
code:
TEST.yml
---
execution:
- executor: selenium
  scenario: simple
  concurrency: 1

scenarios:
 simple:
  requests:
  - http://10.32.1.114:9080
  method: GET
  script: /home/xxxxx/Desktop/XXXXX/src/test/java/Testing_2.java
  additional-classpath: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/lib/selenium-java-2.53.1.jar

modules:
 selenium:
  selenium-tools:
   junit:
    path: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/lib/junit-4.12.jar
    compile-target-java: 1.7
    hamcrest-core: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar

cli-aliases:
  report:
   reporting:
   - blazemeter


Testing_2.java
*****************************************************************''

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@Before
public void setup() {
    driver.navigate().to("http://10.111.111.114:9080");
}

@Test
public void login() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[ng-click='vm.closeTokenForm()']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='text-center']")).getText();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText(user)).click();

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[class='large-12 columns ng-scope']"));
    java.util.List<WebElement> tr_collection = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tbody > tr"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(tr_collection)).size();
}

@After
public void close() {
    driver.close();
}
```

Link to blazemeter forum: [LINK](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/codename-taurus/Running$20multiplay$20test$20with$20junit$20and$20TAURUS%7Csort:relevance/codename-taurus/NsVunFXocNE/Tvw0DwPzAAAJ)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test page load, you can write simple script using request option of scenario. You can write simple scenario page load and run it.

Example:

```
execution:
- executor: selenium
  scenario: simple
  concurrency: 1

scenarios:
 request-example:
  default-address://10.32.1.114:9080
  browser: Firefox
  timeout: 60
  think-time: 2s
  requests:
  - url: /
    actions:
    - clickByCSS("a[ng-click='vm.closeTokenForm()']")
    - waitByCSS("div[class='text-center']"):visible
    - clickByLinkText(user)
    - waitByCSS("table[class='large-12 columns ng-scope']"):visible
```

If you want to measure page load time of different pages(page1.html and page2.html), then you can write:

```
scenarios:
 request-example:
  default-address://10.32.1.114:9080
  browser: Firefox
  timeout: 60
  think-time: 2s
  requests:
  - url: /page1.html
    actions:
    - clickByCSS("a[ng-click='vm.closeTokenForm()']")
    - waitByCSS("div[class='text-center']"):visible
    - clickByLinkText(user)
    - waitByCSS("table[class='large-12 columns ng-scope']"):visible
  - url: /page2.html
    actions:
    - clickByCSS("a[ng-click='vm.closeTokenForm()']")
    - waitByCSS("div[class='text-center']"):visible
    - clickByLinkText(user)
    - waitByCSS("table[class='large-12 columns ng-scope']"):visible
```

The result we see on the Taurus Dashboard. The average time is displayed for each page separately.